# laravel command code exctraction into function

Tags: php, laravel, console

I have console command `php artisan pictures:create-thumbs`, which creates thumbs from big images:

1. Put all images into array.
2. Get rid of some temporary files, which create errors during script execution
3. Process images

**CreateThumbsCommand**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands\Pictures;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Storage;
use Image;

class CreateThumbsCommand extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'pictures:create-thumbs {overwrite?}';
    protected $description = 'Создать миниатюры из оригинальных картинок';

    private $homepage;
    private $news;
    private $pages;
    private $clients;
    private $slider;
    private $src;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->homepage = Storage::disk('local')->allFiles('img/homepage');
        $this->news = Storage::disk('local')->allFiles('img/news');
        $this->pages = Storage::disk('local')->allFiles('img/pages');
        $this->clients = Storage::disk('local')->files('img/clients');
        $this->slider = Storage::disk('local')->files('img/slider');

        $this->src = array_merge(
            $this->homepage,
            $this->news,
            $this->pages,
        );
    }


    // delete temporary files inside @eaDir folders created by synology cloud sync
    public function eaDir(array $infile)
    {
        foreach ($infile as $key => $value) {
            if (str_contains($value, '@eaDir')) {
                print_r('Удаляем ' .$key. ' => ' .$value. "\n");
                unset($infile[$key]);
            }
        }
    }


    public function resize($infile, $outfile, $w, $h)
    {
        $img = Image::make($infile);
        $img->orientate(); // orientate before resize prevent image rotation during resizing
        $img->resize($w, $h, function($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();     // keep aspect ratio
            $constraint->upsize();          // prevent possible upsizing
        });
        $img->save($outfile);
        $this->saved++;
        print_r($img->dirname .'/'. $img->basename. "\n");
    }


    public function handle()
    {

        // delete temporary files inside @eaDir folders created by synology cloud sync
        $this->eaDir($this->src);
        $this->eaDir($this->clients);
        $this->eaDir($this->slider);

        /*

        // delete temporary files inside @eaDir folders created by synology cloud sync
        foreach ($this->src as $key => $value) {
            if (str_contains($value, '@eaDir')) {
                print_r('Удаляем ' .$key. ' => ' .$value. "\n");
                unset($this->src[$key]);
            }
        }
        foreach ($this->clients as $key => $value) {
            if (str_contains($value, '@eaDir')) {
                print_r('Удаляем ' .$key. ' => ' .$value. "\n");
                unset($this->clients[$key]);
            }
        }
        foreach ($this->slider as $key => $value) {
            if (str_contains($value, '@eaDir')) {
                print_r('Удаляем ' .$key. ' => ' .$value. "\n");
                unset($this->slider[$key]);
            }
        }

        */


    .....main code here....
```

eaDir() function needed to avoid this error, which appear when Intervention\Image try to read some temporary file created by synology server.

```
   Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException

  Can't write image data to path (/var/www/storage/app/public/thumbs_lg/pages/@eaDir/3023-322-cobra-8-10.jpg/SYNOFILE_THUMB_S.jpg)

  at vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php:150
    146▕         $data = $this->encode($format, $quality);
    147▕         $saved = @file_put_contents($path, $data);
    148▕
    149▕         if ($saved === false) {
  ➜ 150▕             throw new NotWritableException(
    151▕                 "Can't write image data to path ({$path})"
    152▕             );
    153▕         }
    154▕

  1   app/Console/Commands/Pictures/CreateThumbsCommand.php:124
      Intervention\Image\Image::save("/var/www/storage/app/public/thumbs_lg/pages/@eaDir/3023-322-cobra-8-10.jpg/SYNOFILE_THUMB_S.jpg")

  2   app/Console/Commands/Pictures/CreateThumbsCommand.php:320
      App\Console\Commands\Pictures\CreateThumbsCommand::resize("/var/www/storage/app/img/pages/@eaDir/3023-322-cobra-8-10.jpg/SYNOFILE_THUMB_S.jpg", "/var/www/storage/app/public/thumbs_lg/pages/@eaDir/3023-322-cobra-8-10.jpg/SYNOFILE_THUMB_S.jpg")
http@0bb690b74597:/var/www/steklo-group.ru$
```

But I found that this way it is not working. I got error above anyway.

```
        $this->eaDir($this->src);
        $this->eaDir($this->clients);
        $this->eaDir($this->slider);
```

It is only working when I put foreach directly in handle method. Why it is so? I want to get rid of this to avoid code repeating.

```
        foreach ($this->src as $key => $value) {
            if (str_contains($value, '@eaDir')) {
                print_r('Удаляем ' .$key. ' => ' .$value. "\n");
                unset($this->src[$key]);
            }
        }
        foreach ($this->clients as $key => $value) {
            if (str_contains($value, '@eaDir')) {
                print_r('Удаляем ' .$key. ' => ' .$value. "\n");
                unset($this->clients[$key]);
            }
        }
        foreach ($this->slider as $key => $value) {
            if (str_contains($value, '@eaDir')) {
                print_r('Удаляем ' .$key. ' => ' .$value. "\n");
                unset($this->slider[$key]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error comes from save function which is called in resize function which is nothing to do with eaDir function. File path is wrong. And I can't tell more about that because don't know where $outfile comes from.

Comment: The question was not why resize gives error, but why using `$this->eaDir($this->src)` function doesn't help to delete elements from array. It works only whe foreach is written directly inside handle function (the code which is commented)

Comment: I understand the question, but your question and the error message is not related. I suggest you share the whole class. Maybe there is something else that causes the issue.

Comment: arrays are copy on write, so it is creating a new copy of the array to work on it, not adjusting the original array ... you would have to pass the array as a reference in the method signature to alter the original array passed to the method

Answer (score 0):

answer is adviced by lagbox - to pass the array as a reference &

```
    // delete temporary files inside @eaDir folders created by synology cloud sync
    public function eaDir(array &$infile)
    {
        foreach ($infile as $key => $value) {
            if (str_contains($value, '@eaDir')) {
                print_r('Удаляем ' .$key. ' => ' .$value. "\n");
                unset($infile[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
```